# Inject Router on ngx-restangular

Tags: angular, restangular

I'm using [ngx-restangular](https://github.com/2muchcoffeecom/ngx-restangular) and I want to intercept the response and, if I get a 403, I want to be able to call a service to refresh the token or redirect the user to login page.

AutneticationService constructor:

```
constructor(private router: Router, private restangular: Restangular) {}
```

So, I've this on app.module:

```
    // This function must return observable
      var refreshAccesstoken = function () {

        let auth = new AuthenticationService(undefined, undefined);

        // Here you can make action before repeated request
        // This will throw an error
        // ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'one' of undefined
        // because refresh method uses a constructor dependencie (restangular to make the http request)
        return auth.refresh();
      };

      RestangularProvider.addErrorInterceptor((response, subject, responseHandler) => {

        if (response.status === 403) {

          // How to redirect user to login page or how to call the
          // refreshAccesstoken() function that will make the http call to get new token?

          refreshAccesstoken()
            .switchMap(refreshAccesstokenResponse => {
              //If you want to change request or make with it some actions and give the request to the repeatRequest func.
              //Or you can live it empty and request will be the same.

              // update Authorization header
              response.request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + refreshAccesstokenResponse)

              return response.repeatRequest(response.request);
            })
            .subscribe(
              res => responseHandler(res),
              err => subject.error(err)
            );

            return false; // error handled
          }
          return true; // error not handled
        });
```

This is the AuthenticationService refresh function:

```
refresh() {
        // First way of creating a this.restangular object.
        // Just saying the base URL.
        let baseAuth = this.restangular.one('api').one('refresh');

        return baseAuth.get();
    }
```

Thank you all!